# Why is numba not improving the speed?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

Following function is part of an optimization problem. It is quite simple but is called quite often. An increase in speed would be good. I tried Numba but it seems i have to write it in FORTRAN:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import autojit
# I am using numbapro: from numbapro import autojit

# minimal dataset
n_comp_glob = 2
x_glob = np.random.rand(3*n_comp) 
qs_glob = np.array([100.])
cp_glob =np.tile(1.,n_comp)
cs_glob = np.array( [100.])

def get_denom(n_comp,qs,x,cp,cs_f):
    k = x[0:n_comp]
    sigma = x[n_comp:2*n_comp]
    z = x[2*n_comp:3*n_comp]
    # calculates the denominator in Equ 14a - 14c (Brooks & Cramer 1992)
    a = 0.0 

    for i in range(n_comp):
         a += (sigma[i] + z[i])*( k[i]*(qs/cs)**(z[i]-1) )*cp[i]

    return denom

get_denom_jit=autojit(get_denom)

import timeit
%timeit get_denom(n_comp_glob,qs_glob,x_glob,cp,cs_glob)
10000 loops, best of 3: 22.9 µs per loop
%timeit get_denom_jit(n_comp_glob,qs_glob,x_glob,cp_glob,cs_glob)
10000 loops, best of 3: 27.9 µs per loop
```

If I increase the number of components (n_comp) numba is still not faster than python. Why ?

EDIT:

I tried a code snipped from the [numba documentation](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.9/arrays.html):

```
from numba import *
import numpy as np

mu = 0.1
Lx, Ly = 101, 101
N = 1000


def diffuse_loops(iter_num):
    u = np.zeros((Lx, Ly), dtype=np.float64)
    temp_u = np.zeros_like(u)
    temp_u[Lx / 2, Ly / 2] = 1000.0

    for n in range(iter_num):
        for i in range(1, Lx - 1):
            for j in range(1, Ly - 1):
                u[i, j] = mu * (temp_u[i + 1, j] + temp_u[i - 1, j] +
                            temp_u[i, j + 1] + temp_u[i, j - 1] -
                            4 * temp_u[i, j])

    temp = u
    u = temp_u
    temp_u = temp

return u


def diffuse_array_expressions(iter_num):
    u = np.zeros((Lx, Ly), dtype=np.float64)
    temp_u = np.zeros_like(u)
    temp_u[Lx / 2, Ly / 2] = 1000.0

    for i in range(iter_num):
    u[1:-1, 1:-1] = mu * (temp_u[2:, 1:-1] + temp_u[:-2, 1:-1] +
                          temp_u[1:-1, 2:] + temp_u[1:-1, :-2] -
                          4 * temp_u[1:-1, 1:-1])

    temp = u
    u = temp_u
    temp_u = temp

return u

diffuse_array_expressions_jit = autojit(diffuse_array_expressions)
diffuse_loops_jit = autojit(diffuse_loops)
```

Calling the functions:

```
%timeit diffuse_array_expressions(100)
100 loops, best of 3: 13.9 ms per loop

%timeit diffuse_array_expressions_jit(100)
100 loops, best of 3: 14.8 ms per loop

%timeit diffuse_loops(100)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.88 s per loop

%timeit diffuse_loops_jit(100)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.87 ms per loop
```

So it seems, numba looses its power, when the code is properly implemented in Python. The function above can of course be implenented without a loop:

```
def get_denom_vec(n_comp,qs,x,cp,cs_f):
    k = x[0:n_comp]
    sigma = x[n_comp:2*n_comp]
    z = x[2*n_comp:3*n_comp]
    # calculates the denominator in Equ 14a - 14c (Brooks & Cramer 1992)
    a = 0.0 

    a = (sigma + z)*( k*(qs/cs)**(z-1) )*cp
    denom = np.sum(a) + cs
    return denom

get_denom_vec_jit = autojit(get_denom_vec)

%timeit get_denom_vec_jit(n_comp_glob,qs_glob,x_glob,cp_glob,cs_glob)
1000 loops, best of 3: 223 µs per loop

%timeit get_denom_vec_jit(n_comp_glob,qs_glob,x_glob,cp_glob,cs_glob)
1000 loops, best of 3: 245 µs per loop
```

Comment: Your decoration `@autojit()` might be a no-op to the interpreter. Try `@autojit` instead.

Comment: no, did not improve the speed.

Comment: A few side comments. (1) Do not use the parenthesis in `return`. (2) do not write the function twice, instead use `get_denom_jit = autojit(get_denom)`

Comment: Would it be possible to comment upon down voting, so I can improve the question next time ?

Comment: (3) do not use the same variable names for global variables and function arguments!

Comment: Does this work: `a = np.sum((sigma + z) * (k * (qs/cs)**(z-1)) * cp)`?

Comment: While you commented, i edited the question. It does. And it improves the speed.

Answer (score 5):

The cool thing about numba is that you can find it yourself!

Use

```
@autojit(nopython=True)
```

or

```
numba --annotate myfile.py
```

and iteratively fix the code that cannot be jitted.

Comment: with the `nopython=True` I get following error: `TypingError: Failed at nopython frontend
Undeclared +(float64, array(float64, 1d, C, nonconst))
File "<ipython-input-192-2242b9e57b4d>", line 9`

Comment: @Moritz Exactly, the same you will find with `annotate`. You see, everything that is `PyObject` cannot be optimized, so you need to start changing your code until everything can be jitted. For example, I know that the output of `np.random.rand(3*n_comp)` cannot be jitted in current numba version (there are workarounds). But if I were you I will start by trying to get `autojit` running, or using `jit` (instead of `autojit`) to specify the types that you are providing. Ps.- And see my suggestions to your code!

Comment: Ok, got you. But the output from np.random.rand() is a numpy array. I thought jit can handle arrays ?

Comment: `jit` can 'handle' arrays, but it can't speed up compiled code that creates and manipulates them.